# Add noise effect to a drawing

Tags: android, android-canvas, noise

I'm in the process of creating a custom view for my android application and would like to add a noise overlay over my drawings.

My drawings are pretty standard, arcs, bezier curves, etc.

What would be the way to go with creating a noise overlay over arbitrary shapes, drawn with canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a tileable transparent noise png and cover the canvas with it.

Comment: Yes, something like BitmapShader(bitmap, REPEAT, REPEAT).

Comment: The noise does get applied, but the paint color is not shown, so the color is always the color of noise PNG.

Comment: Try making the noise itself partially transparent so the color shows through.

Comment: It's transparent, I figured it out, I needed to apply the colorfilter to the paint.

Comment: where to find a tileable transparent noise png ?