# Combine background color and texture for Android view

Tags: android, background, textures, android-drawable

For various `View`s in Android, I use a simple background color so far. But in order to make it more interesting, I'd like to add a texture or noise to the background.

Finding [background patterns](http://subtlepatterns.com/) is easy. And making them into a tiled `BitmapDrawable` to be used as a background just as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

But how can I add the color now? You know, I'd like to combine the texture with a color, so that I only have the pattern of the texture and "ignore" or "drop" the color, but instead colorize the pattern with arbitrary colors from code. How is that possible?

Do I have to use the pattern as normal, but then override the `onDraw()` method of the view and add the color somehow? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994289/add-noise-effect-to-a-drawing/6994755#6994755) talks about a `BitmapShader`, but I have no idea how to use that. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Drawable.setColorFilter() method. in most cases you will use a PorterDuffColorFilter or LighingColorFilter

Comment: Thank you! It seems `android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY` usually works best.